# Unable to install npm onoff

Tags: pi-2, node.js, debug

I'm trying to install `onoff` via this command

```
$ npm install onoff
```

Every time I try I get this error. I'm new to pi and programming so I'm completely lost.

Any help?

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $  npm install onoff

/
> epoll@0.1.20 install /home/pi/node_modules/onoff/node_modules/epoll
> node-gyp rebuild

gyp: Call to 'node -e "require('nan')"' returned exit status 1. while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/share/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:344:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:809:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.11-v7+
gyp ERR! command "nodejs" "/usr/bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/pi/node_modules/onoff/node_modules/epoll
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.29
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.12.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN This failure might be due to the use of legacy binary "node"
npm WARN For further explanations, please read
/usr/share/doc/nodejs/README.Debian

npm ERR! epoll@0.1.20 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the epoll@0.1.20 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the epoll package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls epoll
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Linux 4.4.11-v7+
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "onoff"
npm ERR! cwd /home/pi
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.21
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/pi/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't have `node` in your `$PATH`, only `nodejs`. That's a quirk of Debian-based systems due to a naming conflict.

You need to install `nodejs-legacy` to fix.

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy
```

Or, if that does not work, symlink `node` to `nodejs`:

```
sudo ln -s $(which nodejs) /usr/local/bin/node
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying to install in 3 different models of raspberry, this command finally solved my problem in all of them.

sudo npm install -g --unsafe-perm  blynk-library onoff